# modern teams site top navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, modern-team-site

I want to create a navigation at the top of a modern team sites. For now there the only possibility is that i add some ugly looking link at the top of the page. I want to have a navigation with drop down menu just like it was done with classic site.

Comment: For that you have to create SPFx extension.

Comment: Is there a no code solution